# How to set counter field in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I need to increment the field 'post_count' with +1 in elasticsearch 
For ex: In my case When I click a button the post_count need to increment

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_work",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "d989dd8629f8b6cc59faf8a1aa2328c8",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "test",
               "last_name": "amt",
               "post_count":0
            }
         }
      ]
```

Is there any single query to increment post_count in each update

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
POST /test_work/user/d989dd8629f8b6cc59faf8a1aa2328c8/_update
{
   "script" : "ctx._source.post_count+=1"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay, I have tried the query and got error {
   "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting disabled]; ",
   "status": 400
} Where I can enable dynamic script?

Comment: You need to add to `elasticsearch.yml` file this: `script.disable_dynamic: false`

Comment: Just a note, be careful with scripting. Be sure nobody can execute queries against your rest api. Depending on the version you have some options. Best is to migrate to 1.4.x and start using groovy scripts for these purposes. Check the documentation here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also control the increment of the counter using a parameter in your script.
If you are using ES 1.3+ you might get an error saying "dynamic scripting disabled", in order to avoid it you need to specify the script language, in this case groovy.

```
POST /test_work/user/d989dd8629f8b6cc59faf8a1aa2328c8/_update
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.post_count+=increment",
    "params" : {
        "increment" : 4
    },"lang":"groovy"
}
```